# Magento 1.7 my.cnf Optimisation

Tags: mysql, performance, magento, magento-1.7, pagespeed

I am currently running on a cloud server, WITH ukfast

CPU     GenuineIntel, Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2620 0 @ 2.00GHz
Version Parallels Plesk Panel v11.0.9_build110120608.16 os_CentOS 6
OS  CentOS 6.3 (Final) 64-bit
RAM:    6GB

I have 12,000 SKU's but never get over 30 vistors on the site at one time and I am trying to optimise my.cnf file:

This is what I currently have:

```
log_slow_queries = /var/log/mysql-slow.log
long_query_time = 5


key_buffer = 32M
max_allowed_packet = 16M
table_cache = 1024
sort_buffer_size = 48M
read_buffer_size = 92M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 100M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 100M
myisam_max_sort_file_size = 1G
myisam_max_extra_sort_file_size = 1G
myisam_repair_threads = 1
thread_cache_size = 32
query_cache_type = 1
query_cache_size = 200M
query_cache_limit = 2M
max_connections=50
wait_timeout=120
tmp_table_size = 256M
max_heap_table_size = 64M
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 650M
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 24M 

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid}
```

is there anything I am missing or anything I should increase or decrease?

any thoughts / advice would be great.

Answer (score 1):

I have face this problem before. 
Please try this

```
key_buffer = 32M
max_allowed_packet = 16M
table_cache = 1024
sort_buffer_size = 48M
read_buffer_size = 92M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 104M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 100M
myisam_max_sort_file_size = 1024m
myisam_max_extra_sort_file_size = 1024m
myisam_repair_threads = 1
thread_cache_size = 32
query_cache_type = 1
query_cache_size = 256M
query_cache_limit = 2M
max_connections=50
wait_timeout=60
tmp_table_size = 256M
max_heap_table_size = 64M
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 650M
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 24M
```

or you have to change or upgrade your hosting to VPS server. 
Houp this help.
^ ^

Comment: where did you have this?

do you thinking innodb_buffer_pool_size = 650M is big enough my database is 1.8gb